# How can I sort an array of stdClass Objects by a common element within the stdClass Objects?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

How can I sort the following array by `[sequence_number]` in descending order in PHP?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [debate_id] => 1
            [stakeholder_id] => 1
            [sequence_number] => 1
            [title] => SLIDE 1 - STAKEHOLDER 1
            [content] => This is the first slide for STAKEHOLDER 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [debate_id] => 1
            [stakeholder_id] => 1
            [sequence_number] => 4
            [title] => SLIDE 2 - STAKEHOLDER 1
            [content] => This is the second slide for STAKEHOLDER 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [debate_id] => 1
            [stakeholder_id] => 1
            [sequence_number] => 3
            [title] => SLIDE 3 - STAKEHOLDER 1
            [content] => This is the third slide for STAKEHOLDER 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), Here is how you can do it for your example:

```
function compare_func($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->sequence_number == $b->sequence_number) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->sequence_number < $b->sequence_number) ? -1 : 1;
    // You can apply your own sorting logic here.
}

usort($arrayOfObjects, "compare_func");
```

> **usort()** function sorts an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function.

In our case **compare_func** is our user-supplied function.

---

If you want to sort the array by **strings** value you can use [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function inside user-supplied function. Like this,

```
return strcmp($a["title"], $b["title"]);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
usort($array, function($obj1, $obj2) {
    return $obj2->sequence_number - $obj1->sequence_number;
});
```